# Probability of getting $5$ right tickets out of $20$ when selecting $30$ tickets out of $1000$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

In a series of 1000 tickets, there are exactly 20 right tickets. One person selects 30 tickets from the series, find the probability to get 5 right tickets.

Thanks.

Comment: How many ways are there to select the $5$ right tickets? The $25$ left tickets? $30$ any tickets?

Comment: You can easily get an approximation. In the beginning there are $20$ tickets, in the end - $15$ - so on average $17.5$. Hence using Poisson approximation we get $P(N=5)\approx e^{-\lambda}\lambda^5/5!\approx 1.97\cdot 10^{-4}$ for $\lambda=30\cdot 17.5/1000$ which is within $10\%$ of the exact result.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose all $20$ "right" tickets are at the start and the $980$ other tickets are after. The number of ways for $k$ choices in the "right" tickets would be $\binom{20}{k}$ and the number of ways for $30-k$ choices in the other tickets would be $\binom{980}{30-k}$.

---

The probability of getting exactly $5$ "right" tickets would be
$$
\frac{\binom{20}{5}\binom{980}{25}}{\binom{1000}{30}}=0.0001823242734
$$
If you want at least $5$ "right" tickets, we can compute
$$
1-\sum_{k=0}^4\frac{\binom{20}{k}\binom{980}{30-k}}{\binom{1000}{30}}=0.0001948659193
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the discrete random variable for the number of successes obtained. $X$ can be described using a Hypergeometric distribution as follows:

$$P(X=x)=\frac{{20 \choose x}{1000-20 \choose 30-x} }{1000 \choose 30}$$

Hence, the probability of getting $5$ right tickets out of $20$ becomes, $$P(X=5)=\frac{{20 \choose 5}{1000-20 \choose 30-5} }{1000 \choose 30}$$
$$=\frac{{20 \choose 5}{980 \choose 25} }{1000 \choose 30}$$

$$\approx 0.000182$$

---

In general, you can use the hypergeometric distribution to model situations where you have a collection of $N$ objects, which are either success or failure (binary types). If there are $r$ number of successes, and you pick $n$ objects at random without replacement, then your hyp. function becomes,

$$f(x)=P(X=x)=\frac{{r \choose x}{N-r \choose n-x} }{N \choose n}$$

In this case, we have $N=1000, r=20, n=30.$